# How to apply page break style for a div in iframes while printing window

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to apply a page break before property for a div within in an iframe (will have multiple iframes) while printing window.
Example:-

```
--Header Data--
   --Iframe1--
        div style="page-break-before:always"
   --Iframe2--
        div style="page-break-before:always"
      .
      .
      .
```

I tried @media print, inline style but none of them works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code and see if it works for you

```
@media all {
    .page-break { display: none; }
}

@media print {
    .page-break { display: block; page-break-before: always; }
}
```

and your html

```
<h1>Page Title</h1>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content block -->
<div class="page-break"></div>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content block -->
<div class="page-break"></div>
<!-- content block -->
<!-- content -->
```

see ref [here](https://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks)